# Alignment of two tables with Bootstrap grid system on small devices and desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a HTML page that consists of two tables. On small devices, I want those tables to stack vertically. On Desktop, I want them to appear next to each other. Here's my Page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>th is 0</th>
              <th>th is 1</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>cell is row 0, column 0</td>
              <td>cell is row 0, column 1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>th is 0</th>
              <th>th is 1</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>cell is row 0, column 0</td>
              <td>cell is row 0, column 1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is that the tables are always aligned vertically, even on desktop.  How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Works as expected ...http://www.bootply.com/NC9CSRS2zB... Doing a snippet or your code on the actual question also works fine.

Comment: You're right, works just like intended. Must have missed something... thanks anyways!